# What is the correct way to store a token for application development?

Tags: android, ios

The other developer and I have two different views on storing sensitive data. So, the token is only accessible at run time in a global variable right now, but I suggested moving the token to be stored in the Keychain and therefore encrypted, but he says that it is more secure to be stored as a global object because it is not being written to a file. However, I feel that global variables get stored to the heap and it's easy to find the memory location of that variable.

Currently looks like this:

```
const TOKEN_STORE = { oauth_token: "", };
```

What is the correct way to store a token for application development?

Comment: While I am tempted to say the Keychain is better, the problem is the end user will be able to get it either way if they are determined enough.

Comment: I suppose what I should ask is which is more secure, and I need some articles or something to back that up - I understand that neither way is fully secure. I've always been taught to store sensitive information in the keychain, but when questioned I have nothing to back up why I feel it is more secure.

Comment: The keychain is definitely the better place to store them.

Comment: Even if it is not needed between sessions - the token that is? Do you have anything to back that up? He says, quite rightly that when you pull it from the keychain you will be storing it in a varaible (a local one though), he says it does the same thing, but I disagree because you aren't storing it in a global variable but a local one.

Comment: That depends on the longevity of the token. If it's short-lived (e.g. becomes invalid in a matter of minutes), it can and should remain in RAM. I assumed you speak of longer-lived refresh tokens, which remain valid for months or even years, then they should be persisted into the keychain.

Comment: so the longevity of the token is a day, but we just "log" you out when you close the app.

Comment: There's not much difference between a long-lived local variable and a global variable. Storing it in the keychain will put it in a local variable if your retrieve it. But the point of the keychain is that you should not need to retrieve its content, the cryptographic operation should be performed using its API, which use the secure TEE to perform them: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore However, I do not know if that's possible with oauth.

Comment: @HannahCarney And when you re-open the app, do you ask the user to re-authenticate?

Comment: The user always reauthenticates when you open the app but the last token is still valid until the end of the day if you dont log back in, and I think the difference between local and global variables seems to be that local variables are stored in the stack, whereas global are stored in the heap. I think the heap is easier to access as a hacker, but I am not one so I am not sure.

Comment: @HannahCarney If your concern is whether the stack or the heap is a more "secure" place to store variables, the answer is both are equally unsafe.

Comment: My answer is really which one (Storing in memory) or (storing in keychain) is more secure, but it sounds like neither is secure from what you are saying, haha.

Comment: In your use case, they both offer the same level of (in)security. You should favor the easiest to maintain and less likely to be misused and cause a bug in the future.